# How well-rehearsed was General Hux's speech?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

> Today is the end of the Republic—the end of a regime that acquiesces to disorder!
>   At this very moment, in a system far from here, the New Republic lies to the galaxy,
>   while secretly supporting the treachery of the loathsome Resistance!
>   This fierce machine which you have built, upon which we stand,
>   will bring an end to the Senate, to their cherished fleet;
>   All remaining systems will bow to the First Order,
>   And will remember this AS THE LAST DAY OF THE REPUBLIC!

I'm wondering about this last line here.  It's kind of redundant with the rest of the speech.  The first time I saw the movie,  I was expecting him to say something like "the last day of life as they know it" and was a little surprised when he circled back to the words he used at the start.  I know repetition is a powerful rhetorical device (especially so with propaganda) but this apparently rushed choice of words still doesn't make sense to me.

So, did Hux make an on-the-fly change to his speech or was the odd redundancy actually planned?

Comment: In-universe, almost all the lines are ad-libbed.

Comment: I can't see how this could be answered in-universe.

Comment: Pretty confident that in-universe he will have pre-prepared his speech given that this is one of the biggest moments ever and he won't want to mess it up.

Comment: The whole thing seems to have been very much planned and organized, so I suspect he prepared his speech.

Comment: It's a conclusion... Conclusions are often reinforcements of the main idea. I don't see a reason that this would be an unexpected choice of words.

Comment: Agreed with all of the above.  The premise of this question doesn't make sense, and it's not appropriately answerable regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no particular indication (from the script or various novelisation) that his speech was anything other than carefully planned.

That being said, the slight redundancy you've noted in his final line was as a result of the original line (and its rhetorical flair) being trimmed for the final cut of the film. In the earlier version, evident only in the novels, the speech read as follows...

> *“This fierce machine which you have built, and upon which we stand,
> will bring a final end to the worthless Senate and the New Republic’s
> cherished fleet.” His amplified voice echoed through the mountains.
> “When this day is done, all the remaining systems will bow to the
> dictates of the First Order. All will remember this as **the last day
> of the last Republic!”***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah.  "The last day of the last Republic."  That makes sense.